# why isn't this valid java (tm)?

Tags: java, tm

I have a  problem when I try install Cpn tools . show warning message

```
"the installer could not find a valid java(tm) on this machine.
 supported versions:
Vendor: Any min.1.6 max.any"
```

what's mean? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: install java then?

Answer (score 2):

You need to download [**java**](https://java.com/en/download/) and install it. Then config JAVA_HOME and PATH refer [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java).

Make sure you can get java version when typing
`java -version`
 in command line.

Comment: from where I can install java ? Can you give me a link?

Comment: You can also type "where can I install Java" into any search engine, and it will probably be the very first result.